# Cannot receive inline images from email using php imap?

Tags: php, imap

I try this below code, cannot receive inline images from email using php imap?

```
$emailAddress = "demo@demo.com" ; 
$emailPassword = "ps";
$domainURL = 'demo.com'; 
$useHTTPS = true; 
$inbox = imap_open('{'.$domainURL.':143/notls}INBOX',$emailAddress,$emailPassword) or die('Cannot connect to domain:' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
if($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2));
        $output .= 'Subject: '.$overview[0]->subject.'<br />';
        $output .= 'Body: '.$message.'<br />';
        $output .= 'From: '.$overview[0]->from.'<br />';
        $output .= 'Date: '.$overview[0]->date.'<br />';
    }
    echo $output;
}
imap_close($inbox);
```

My output is:

```
src="cid:ii_15a0880348d13b6e"
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: image source <img src="cid:ii_15a0880348d13b6e"> cannot show, how to fix this problem, please help me